# RKMappingOperation doesn't connect relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to perform object mapping manually by using `RKMappingOperation`, but it seems like it's not connecting the relationships which are set in `RKEntityMapping`.

**I've created a demo project, you can check out here: https://github.com/HiveHicks/RKMappingOperationTest**

There are two entities in the model: `Employee` and `Department` with a many-to-one relationship called (department can have many employees, and one employee can work only in one department). There is also a class called `TestOperation`, which performs mapping in background using `RKMappingOperation`. As you can see in `-[TestOperation mappingForObject:]`, I set up a connection for employee mapping like this:

```
    [mapping addConnectionForRelationship:EmployeeRelationships.department connectedBy:@{
            EmployeeAttributes.departmentGuid : DepartmentAttributes.guid
    }];
```

However, when the operation finishes, the mapped managed objects have all the attributes, but no relationship

[image]

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that `RKMapperOperation` maps attributes for managed objects synchronously, but creates asynchronous operation for connecting relationships. That leads to the following situation:

1. When `-[RKMapperOperation execute:]` returns, I save the context. All the attributes are there, but relationship is not, because `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation` is added to the queue, on which I am right now.
2. `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation` only sets the relationship, it doesn't save the context.
3. I'm left with a dirty context and no idea about when to save it, because `RKMapperOperationDelegate`'s `mapperDidFinishMapping:` method is called **before** `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation` starts.

The picture below proves what I just said

[image]

So, the solution that I see right now is to create new operation queue in `SyncOperation`, add `RKMapperOperation` to it, and then wait until all the operations in this internal queue finish executing. WOW. Sounds like a hack. I'll give it a try right now.

**UPDATE 2**

It works with the solution I described. Solved. I've commited the final version.

Comment: Show the code. What data source are you providing?

Comment: @Wain the code is posted on github: https://github.com/HiveHicks/RKMappingOperationTest

Comment: The setup of RKMappingOperation can be found in `-[TestOperation mapObject:withMapping:cache:]`

Comment: I guess that this is caused by RKMappingOperation connecting relationships in a separate operation that uses weak reference to the managed object context. By the time my own TestOperation finishes, the context is dead, and so RKMappingOperation is left with nil instead of MOC, that's why it can't perform connection. Is there a way to wait until *ALL* actions of RKMappingOperation are finished before returning from `performMapping:`?

Comment: I tried creating global MOC (retained by app delegate) and use it in TestOperation, so that it won't die when operation finishes, but it didn't help.

Comment: What situation are you actually trying to replicate with this test? Is there a reason for not using an object manager?

Comment: @Wait yes, there is. I need to create HTTP request myself, because it's rather complex (I didn't show it in the project as it bears no relation to the actual problem). So mapping is the only thing I want from RestKit in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, is there a reason you don't use `RKMapperOperation` to process the whole response instead of breaking it up yourself?

Comment: @Wain I made changes to the code, and now it uses `RKMapperOperation`. I've updated the question to reflect what I found out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create temporary operation queue, add `RKMapperOperation` to it and call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on this queue. After that, your context is guaranteed to have all the needed relationships set.

The working project is posted on github: https://github.com/HiveHicks/RKMappingOperationTest

```
id<RKManagedObjectCaching> cache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:_context];
RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *dataSource =
        [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:_context cache:cache];

RKMapperOperation *mapperOperation = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:objects mappingsDictionary:@{
        [NSNull null] : [self mapping]
}];
mapperOperation.mappingOperationDataSource = dataSource;
mapperOperation.delegate = self;

NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
operationQueue.name = @"Internal SyncOperation queue";

[operationQueue addOperation:mapperOperation];
[operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

[_context performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    if (![_context saveToPersistentStore:&saveError]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving to store: %@", saveError);
    }
}];
```